# Does Delphi support explicit specialization of generic methods?

Tags: delphi, generics

In C++, you can explicitly define a unique specialization for a templated function, like (to [steal an example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/template-specialization-c/))

```
// A generic sort function 
template <class T>
void sort(T arr[], int size)
{
    // code to implement Quick Sort
}

// Template Specialization: A function 
// specialized for char data type
template <>
void sort<char>(char arr[], int size)
{
    // code to implement counting sort
}
```

Is there a way to do the equivalent with Delphi generic methods? When I try

```
function TryStrConv<T>(S: string; var Val: T): boolean;
function TryStrConv<float>(S: string; var Val: float): boolean;
```

I get warnings about how I have to use the `Overload` directive.

What I'm hoping to get is a way to write a generic `TryStrConv` where the default instantiation returns false and does nothing, while the int and float instantiations, which I want to provide explicitly, use `TryStrToInt` and `TryStrToFloat`. Alternatively, if there's a generic conversion facility in Delphi that I'm missing, I'd like to get pointed at it.

Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot at declaration already fill the generic argument. You either overload with one generic method and one without being generic like this:

```
function TryStrConv<T>(S: string; var Val: T): boolean; overload;
function TryStrConv(S: string; var Val: Extended): boolean; overload;
```

But need to be aware that it only picks the non generic one for Extended and not the other floating point types Delphi has like Double or Single.

Another way can be if you are on a version of Delphi XE7 or higher to use the new intrinsic functions to branch the generic methods implementation (it gets resolved at compiletime and the non executed path gets eliminated). It could for example look like this (I omitted the type of the TryStrConv method but you know in Delphi you cannot have generic standalone routines but they have to be methods of some type even if just static):

```
function TryStrConv<T>(S: string; var Val: T): boolean;
begin
  if GetTypeKind(T) = tkFloat then
  begin
    // do stuff with val being a float type, still need to handle the different float types though 
    case GetTypeData(TypeInfo(T)) of
      ftDouble: DoStuffWithDouble; 
      // if you need to pass Val here you might need to do some pointer
      // ref/deref hardcasts like PDouble(@Val)^ because otherwise you 
      // are not allowed to cast type T to Double (or any other type)
      ....
    end; 
  else
    Result := False;
end;
```

Comment: I think the right approach for me here is to write a bunch of overloaded wrappers for TryStrTo***XXX*** and let overload resolution figure it out, because I am OK with a compile-time error if there's not an overload. The caller of this conversion will itself be a generic method, and it will have a variable of the right type to make the resolution work.

Comment: In other words: no, you can't have specializations like in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar like this:

```
Type
  TCalc = record
    class function TryStrConv(S: string; var Val: Double): boolean; overload; static;
    class function TryStrConv(S: string; var Val: integer): boolean; overload; static;
    class function TryStrConv<T>(S: string; var Val: T): boolean;  overload; static;
  end;

{ TCalc }

class function TCalc.TryStrConv(S: string; var Val: Double): boolean;
begin
  Result := TryStrToFloat(s,Val);
end;

class function TCalc.TryStrConv(S: string; var Val: integer): boolean;
begin
  Result := TryStrToInt(S,Val);
end;

class function TCalc.TryStrConv<T>(S: string; var Val: T): boolean;
begin
  Result := false;
end;
```

And testing:

```
var
  iVal : Integer;
  dVal : Double;
  sVal : String;
  ok : Boolean;
begin
  ok := TCalc.TryStrConv('12',iVal);
  WriteLn(ok,' ',iVal);                  // True 12
  ok := TCalc.TryStrConv('12',dVal);    
  WriteLn(ok,' ',dVal);                  // True 1.2 E+1
  ok := TCalc.TryStrConv('12',sVal);
  WriteLn(ok,' ',sVal);                  // False
  ReadLn;
end.
```

As Stefan says: You will have to write a specific function for each of the float types.